# Magento product zoom files

Tags: magento, product, zooming

Can someone please tell me what are the Javascript files for default Magento Product Zoom extension. On my site its not working and seems I am missing some files.

please reply.

Answer (score 1):

That depends of your magento version: 
Community edition have it's zoom stored in js/varien/product.js (Product.Zoom object)
Enterprise one in /skin/frontend/enterprise/default/js/jqzoom (additional outdated  jquery zoom)
I believer that your scripts are loaded fine.
The problem can be in "image size" vs "image-frame" size.
If product image is less or equal then dimensions of an html element (set in css for CE), then zoom is not performed (no use of extra large image of bad quality).
So check size of your uploaded image. Or just upload really huge one to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The zoom files are in the folder skin/frontend///js/ 
There you can see the js files or folders (jqzoom).